# Misaligning pointers to save space: How to do this cleanly without UB?

Tags: linux, pointers, c++11, x86, memory-alignment

Consider I have a struct like this:

```
struct X{
    int* somePtr;
    uint16_t someCounter;
}
```

I use this struct extensively in very huge arrays (hundreds of millions of `X`s). Since C++ aligns the pointer to an 8-byte boundary, the struct uses up 16 bytes. Without this alignment, the struct would only use 10 bytes which is what I want to achieve, because the extra 6 bytes really cost a lot of memory.

So I tried this using char arrays and the union hack:

```
struct X{
    char somePtr[8];
    uint16_t someCounter;

    int* getPtr(){
        union U { int* ptr; char chars[8]; };
        U u;
        u.chars = somePtr;
        return u.ptr;
    }
}
```

This yields the desired 10 byte struct. My question now is: What are the drawbacks of this approach? Does it trigger undefined behaviour? Is this the best way to achieve "packed" structs in C++11 or are there ones which are better/cleaner? Is using such packed structs a good idea if a have huge arrays of the `X` structs?

My Platform is x86 linux, but it would be cool if the solution was fully portable.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Computer RAM is quite cheep. So is disk space. Modern OS do enable swapping of pages of memory to/from HDD. You can even purchase SSDs

Comment: @NPE: Added as last paragraph.

Comment: @EdHeal Technical limitations are probably the primary reason.

Comment: @gexicide You should really be adding that as a tag.

Comment: @EdHeal: Maybe I am too old school but I like the idea of saving around 40% of memory instead of telling my client to buy some more terabytes of RAM or accepting that the process will swap like hell :).

Comment: @cybermonkey: What exactly?

Comment: @NPE: To quote my question: "I use this struct extensively in very huge arrays (hundreds of millions of Xs)."

Comment: @gexicide The [tag:linux] and [tag:x86] tags, I submitted a suggested edit, its up to you whether you want to accept or not. By 'technical limitations' I meant that any computer system has a limit on how much memory it can have, hard drive space, etc. If you've hit the hard-limit there's nothing much you can really do- by optimizing the program to be more efficient this hard-limit is less likely to be hit.

Comment: @gexicide - This depends on how you are accessing the memory. But memory is quite cheap. Probably a lot cheaper than a programmer working on the problem for a month

Comment: Apparently this robo-reviewer (Piotr S) didn't read the question nor the comments properly: http://puu.sh/du7pC/d305208e94.png

Comment: `pragma pack` anyone?

Comment: @cybermonkey: Already accepted

Comment: @gexicide Yeah, I saw that (thanks).

Comment: Since alignment is a compiler-specific thing, why don't you use a compiler-specific solution (`pragma pack`) as @bolov already said?

Comment: @cybermonkey: Depending on how exactly the used alternative looks like, 40% wasted memory also means a significant performance drop. Memory (especially main memory, not to talk about SSDs or HDD) is very slow compared to the processing pipeline on an x86 Processor.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, your proposed solution should work fine. The drawbacks are complexity and possibly performance.

An alternative might be to replace the single array of `structs` with an array of pointers and a separate array of counters. This should sidestep the padding issue.

Comment: I also considered the idea of storing two arrays. However, there is a lot of point access (e.g. `largeArray[x]`) to these arrays and the additional cache miss would probably hit me hard.

Comment: @gexicide: I was in the same situation as you and in my situation it turned out that I notice any difference between having two arrays as opposed to having one. I can't say for sure whether that will be true for you too, but it's probably worth a shot, especially if the two arrays aren't accessed with exactly the same frequency.